# Прототипное наследование, переопределение метода родителя

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, имеются два конструктора, в прототипах которых определены методы calc. Вопрос заключается вот в чем: в прототипном методе calc (ClassB.prototype.calc) для переопределения метода вызывается метод родителя calc (ClassA.prototype.calc.apply(this)), как можно вызвать этот метод не зная имени родителя?

```js
function ClassA(a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = 1;
  return this.a + this.b + this.c;
}

ClassA.prototype.calc = function() {
  return this.a + this.b + this.c;
}

let class1 = new ClassA(2, 2);

function ClassB(d, f) {
  this.d = d;
  this.e = f;
  this.f = 10;
  ClassA.apply(this, arguments);
}

ClassB.prototype = Object.create(ClassA.prototype);
ClassB.prototype.constructor = ClassB;

ClassB.prototype.calc = function() {
  var jas = ClassA.prototype.calc.apply(this);
  return jas + this.d + this.e + this.f;
}

let class2 = new ClassB(20, 20);

console.log(class1.calc());
console.log(class2.calc());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) применяя его к объекту `this`.

После первого применения в возвращенном объекте будет метод `calc`, определенный в `ClassB.prototype`, после второго - в `ClassA.prototype`

```
var classBproto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
var classAproto = Object.getPrototypeOf(classBproto);
```

И уже вызывать метод calc из `classAproto`.

Пример:

```js
function ClassA(a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = 1;
  return this.a + this.b + this.c;
}

ClassA.prototype.calc = function() {
  return this.a + this.b + this.c;
}

let class1 = new ClassA(2, 2);

function ClassB(d, f) {
  this.d = d;
  this.e = f;
  this.f = 10;
  ClassA.apply(this, arguments);
}

ClassB.prototype = Object.create(ClassA.prototype);
ClassB.prototype.constructor = ClassB;

ClassB.prototype.calc = function() {
  var jas = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)).calc.apply(this);
  return jas + this.d + this.e + this.f;
}

let class2 = new ClassB(20, 20);

console.log(class1.calc());
console.log(class2.calc());
```

Comment: Еще подойдет вариант   var jas = this.__proto__.__proto__.calc.apply(this);

Comment: @victor, `__proto__` - это обертка над `Object.getPrototypeOf`

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сохранить прототипы родителя в переменной `parent`, другого способа обратиться к нему без имени класса наверное и нет, потому что в `classB`, вы затираете метод родителя своей реализацией, а ссылки на методы родителя у вас не остаётся.

```
ClassB.prototype = Object.create(ClassA.prototype);
ClassB.prototype.constructor = ClassB;
ClassB.prototype.parent = Object.create(ClassA.prototype);
ClassB.prototype.calc = function() {
  var jas = this.parent.calc.apply(this);
  return jas + this.d + this.e + this.f;
}
```

Comment: _вы затираете метод родителя своей реализацией_ - на самом деле нет. затирается метод объекта, который был вернут функцией Object.create, но это не тот же объект, что и ClassA.prototype